# Can someone translate this for me? It's a family heirloom

Tags: traditional-characters, classical-chinese

[image: My grandfather Found this during WWII. Would love to know what it says]

My grandfather found this during WWI, would love to know what it says

Comment: `天朗气清 五峰山?`, sorry I can't recognize the last one character. `天朗气清` means good weather, `the sky is clear and bright`, `五峰山` seems to be a mountain's name.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know how else to get a chinese translation! I googled with no luck

Comment: You can turn to online dictionary, or google translation. If still can't get the right answer, just show your effort/result and ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with songyuanyao. But I want to add some more.

The right column is 天朗氣清. It should be the title of the paint. 天朗氣清 = clear(朗) sky(天) and fresh(清) air(氣).

The left column should be (I think) 五峰山樵. 五峰山 = a mountain in China. woodman = 樵. It is the pen name of the author. But I could be wrong since googling it gives nothing.

Comment: Correct. And the stamps below read `五老峰` and `拙哉`.